# How to split one worksheet into multiple workbooks based on column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take one master document and split it into seperate excel files based on the values in my column "Business Unit".  The new sheets will be named after their business unit and they should contain only the data in the rows containing that particular business unit.  IE all ACH labeled rows need to be in the new ach folder.  This code is currently making the sheets based on segment "column A".  It is also only giving me the data in those rows that match the segment name IE instead of getting ACH ACH and ACH ACH 1 ACH ACH2 I am just getting ACH ACH.So I either set up my filtering wrong or i set up my copying wrong.  I just can't tell.

```
Sub ExtractToNewWorkbook()

    Dim ws     As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew  As Workbook
    Dim rData  As Range
    Dim rfl    As Range
    Dim Business_Unit  As String
    Dim sfilename As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All Functions Final")

    'Apply advance filter in sheet

    With ws

        Set rData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp))
        .Columns(.Columns.Count).Clear
        .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), Unique:=True


        For Each rfl In .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).End(xlUp))

            Business_Unit = rfl.Text

            Set wsNew = Workbooks.Add

            sfilename = Business_Unit & ".xlsx"

            'Set the Location

            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sfilename
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ws.Activate
            rData.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Business_Unit
            rData.Copy
            Windows(Business_Unit).Activate
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

        Next rfl

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End With

    ws.Columns(Columns.Count).ClearContents
    rData.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have some data that can put this code into perspective?

Comment: I have this spreadsheet i made from 130 sheets.  I normalized all the data and now i need to put the data back into 130 separate sheets.  The second column in my sheet with the header "Business Unit" has the names of the units and that is what i need the sheets to be. there are 130 Business Units so i needs their data put into sheets with their name.  Example the entire row for all cells that contain ACH in the second column need to be placed into a new sheet called ACH.  Right now it is making sheets with the names unique in column 1 and it is only giving me the header and random data